# Time taken on first run with AS 2.0 and gradle 2.0

Tags: android, android-studio-2.0, android-gradle-2.0

Recently i have upgraded `Android Studio` from `1.5` to `2.0`.

With that i am using `gradle 2.0.0`

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'
```

But there seems some issue with it, whenever i am running my app for first time, it is showing while/black screen for 10-15 seconds.

There is nothing i am doing on applicationClass or launcher activity, but then also it is taking this much time.

I don't know whether it is issue with `AS 2.0` or `Gradle 2.0.0`. Strange thing is that it is working properly on emulator, it is just taking time on device. So there might be possibility of device RAM or processing issues, but i have checked it in 10-12 devices and all devices have same issue.

Problem arise when i am running my application for first time, then after it is working as usual and loads launcher activity within fraction of seconds.

Can anyone please help me in this?

Comment: So, you are referring to the fact that the Instant Run feature on an emulator is practically instant and you somehow expect a physical device to act the same?

Comment: but when i am clearing data from app on device, and then running it, first time it showing same white/black screen for10-15 seconds, at that time device is not connected so it means there is no connection of instant run.

Comment: I'm not sure what screen you are meaning. When the app itself runs? Or as it is installed?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36623917/first-launch-take-long-time-in-android

Comment: @cricket_007 when you are running app for first time, whether its first time after installation or first time after clearing cache data.

Comment: Turn off your instant run and your problem will be fixed.

Comment: @Amir that doesn't seems solution, you mean to say that is bug in instant-run??

Comment: I think so. Also your min API should be above 15 to instant run work properly.

Comment: Also it's not affect your release APK. because of some initialization in debug mode this happen in first launch.

Comment: If that is problem with instant-run, it should work properly when i disconnect device. But it is not.

Comment: When you upgraded to AS 2.0 did you got warning about JDK version.If yes  please update your JDK.Your should be 1.8@ Ravi Rupareliya

Comment: I think its bug in instant run...same thing is happening with my app too...device holds on for white screen for 10-15 seconds on its first launch and even after disconnecting it from AS same thing happend [Another Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36575229/android-studio-2-0-pause-white-screen-on-app-first-run)

Comment: I have also experienced this issue and in my case the first run time improves significaltly setting the `minSdkVersion` to `21` as stated here: http://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/building/building-studio.html#instant-run

Comment: if you feel 2.0 version is issue then you can try updating studio to 2.1

Comment: i have the same problem and version 2.1 didn't help

Comment: what i'm doing now is using gradle version 1.5.1 or 1.5.0 not sure, and its running better in my devise

Comment: I am facing this issue in 2.1.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> there seems some issue with it, whenever i am running my app for first
>   time, it is showing while/black screen for 10-15 seconds.

I guess you have issue of **Cold Start** in your application.

> **Cold Start :**
>
> When a user launches an application, Android creates a new process
>   that, during it charge, shows a black/white screen which is built with
>   the application theme, or the theme of the activity that is the entry
>   point.
>
> This load can be increased if our application is complex and
>   overwrites the application object, which is normally used to
>   initialize the analytics, error reporters, etc.

**Solution :**

1. Specify `android:windowBackground` in your application theme.
2. Add Splash screen to your app.

For detailed information please check, http://saulmm.github.io/avoding-android-cold-starts

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As [documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-studio.html#instant-run) describe :

> Instant Run pushes updated code and resources to your connected device
>   or emulator by performing a hot swap, warm swap, or cold swap. It
>   automatically determines the type of swap to perform based on the type
>   of change you made.

Also document mentioned it's not Bug with **instant run** :

> When you deploy a clean build, Android Studio instruments your app to
>   allow Instant Run to push code and resource updates. Although updating
>   the running app happens much more quickly, **the first build may take
>   longer to complete**.

You can improve the build process by configuring a few DexOptions settings:

```
android {
  ...
  dexOptions {
    maxProcessCount 4 // this is the default value
    javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
  }
}
```

- [JavaMaxHeapSize](http://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.DexOptions.html#com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.DexOptions:javaMaxHeapSize)
- [maxProcessCount](http://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.DexOptions.html#com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.DexOptions:javaMaxHeapSize)

Answer (score 0):

In android studio, open preferences. In the search bar(preferences dialog) type instant run or Navigate to Build, Execution, Deployment > Instant Run and uncheck all the options. But of course, you will lose the power of instant run.

Answer (score 0):

Change your classpath

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'
```

to your previous build version (for e.g)

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
```