# White screen at start when running debug variant

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio, android-build

Recently, I noticed running my App's `debug` variant of my first time - meaning *installing it the first time*, a **white screen** shows up *before splash screen*, which stays for quite long time `~ 15 sec on Nexus 6`.

*Also happens if I clear data, and run again.*

At first I thought it was a *side-effect* of any patch, so *I rolled back to the working published revision*.

But the same thing occurred. Although if I install from `Play`, **it works normally**.

So, I ran a 'release' build, and voila! It was working normally. It's obviously not caused by the Application class, or any other code change, as that would happen for the release also.

It's also obviously not the same as brief white screen problem mentioned elsewhere, like this ([thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37437037)):
So when I applied the `transparent theme` to `splash` as suggested there, after tapping on the App, the *phone screen froze*, *no touch worked* for the *same amount of time*, then *Splash* showed.

Not getting any clue why changing to `debug` will cause such a huge problem. And why first run only.

Comment: Maybe this would help a bit [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36575229/android-studio-2-0-pause-white-screen-on-app-first-run?answertab=votes#tab-top) by turning off the `instant run`

Comment: check this link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vw1G1s73DsY&index=74&list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc9CBxr3BVjPTPoDPLdPIFCE

Comment: you can handle it by settings a custom theme. Do not set splash directly

Comment: still having this problem with android studio 4.1.2. instant run does not exist anymore. any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because you're using Android studio instant run.

You can disable it like this:

> Properties -> Instant Run -> uncheck 'Enable Instant Run...'

Comment: nope this is wrong, I am using Android studio 2.2.3 , first i also thought it is because of instant run, but it is not. sorry brother.

Comment: @AJay disabling instant run resolved it for me, so I accepted it.

Answer (score 0):

As per my experience when you working with app pls ignore this thing but when you provide a build to client/tester please make sign build and check same in your device this problem resolve. Still, i'm found the perfect solution with debugging till you may use this. ( this is only happening API 24 and later).

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to say.. but disabling instant run resolved it.

Comment: Yes, my mean is Generate Signed build from the android studio it was resolved.

Comment: that is an extra level of work.. whereas the problem and the solution has already been identified.

Answer (score 0):

make a drawable like this one with name background_splash

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:drawable="@color/gray"/>

    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

then in styles add the style like this:

```
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background_splash</item>
</style>
```

then in your activity in manifest add your style

```
<activity
    android:name=".SplashActivity"
    android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
```

more information:
[Splash Screens the Right Way](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/)

also you can check android performance patterns episods:
[android performance patterns](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vw1G1s73DsY&index=74&list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc9CBxr3BVjPTPoDPLdPIFCE)

Answer (score 0):

If You have put `android:debuggable="false""` in Manifest file
Change it to

```
android:debuggable="true"
```

or
Properties -> Instant Run -> uncheck 'Enable Instant Run...'

Answer (score 0):

Properties -> Instant Run -> uncheck 'Enable Instant Run...'