# Android App is taking too much time to load for the first time after installation, showing blank screen

Tags: android, performance, android-layout

New to android, I have developed an Android App. Which when I am installing for the first time, it's taking too much time for the first time only. It's showing blank screen only. I am getting only below logs.

```
/PackageName W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/PackageName-1/lib/x86 
/PackageName W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/PackageName-1/lib/x86
```

Please help if anyone else faced same issue.

Comment: Loading for the first time on emulator or installing the APK on your phone?

Comment: Also is that the full value of the log message? not something like `W/System: ClassLoader`?

Comment: Yes its like  W/System: only

Comment: Reference this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35926287/classloader-referenced-unknown-path-data-app

Comment: That I have Read already read But didn't help My main Issue is Loading taking too much time

Comment: Could be this : http://stackoverflow.com/q/36575229/4252352 - Instant Run

Comment: Taking too much time on what? The emulator or on the phone? Is it the first time you're "running" it from Android Studio or are you calling an already installed apk and then it's taking a while?

Comment: on Both (phone as well as on Emulator) and installing from both Android Studio as well as from APK . its taking too much time to reach my first splash Screen's Activity's on create method

Comment: Uninstall the apk, turn off Instant Run (if enabled) - File>Settings>Build,Deployment>Instant Run and try runnning/installing again.

Comment: Thanks Mark, Yes It Helped, Let me try this With APK. What's the reason behind this.

Comment: Yes Mark, Now its Working Fine for Me , Issue was with instant run only, but what can be the reason behind this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uninstall the apk, turn off Instant Run (if enabled) - File>Settings>Build,Deployment>Instant Run and try runnning/installing again