# White screen or app launch lag on devices with Android >= Lollipop

Tags: android, app-startup, app-launcher

When I start app (First launch or Launching after killing it through task stack), It takes around 5-6 seconds to come to Launcher screen and shows white screen.

When I made launcher activity translucent then still same app lag time is there.

One more thing is that if I play with application for some time like 30 min and kill it through task stack then it take much more time like 15-20 seconds to launch.

I have read all blogs and answers on stack-over flow but it did not help.

Some information regarding above scenario:

1. When app takes more than 10 seconds then I observed that it does verification of objects as it show in logs.
2. I have instance and variable in Application class to use it throughout app.
3. I have GCM also in app.

Comment: You are probably making too much thing during onCreate and this way, your Activity is taking time to prepare the screen... Is it impossible to help without any code...

Comment: If it is blocker for a release you could show a splash screen as a quick fix. But the main issue lies in the activity. Probably you are doing too much in home screen. You layouts are too complex too be rendered in lesser time.

Comment: post your code,may be you are doing lots of task in the oncreate or main thread.or check GCM token getting implemented properly.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions. It worked for me by disabling Instant Run.
I checked on this link [Android Studio 2.0 - pause/white screen on App first run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36575229/android-studio-2-0-pause-white-screen-on-app-first-run)