# Delay in opening app when installed first time and white screen appears

Tags: android

When i install the app from the Studio or by copy to memory card. First time it shows white screen, then work normally.I notice the following log:

---

> I/dex2oat: dex2oat took 27.579ms (threads: 4) arena alloc=0B java
>   alloc=39KB native alloc=439KB free=840KB I/dex2oat:
>   /system/bin/dex2oat --debuggable
>   --dex-file=/data/data/com.company.package/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_9-classes.dex
>   --oat-file=/data/user/0com.company.package/cache/slice-slice_9-classes.dex
>
> I/dex2oat: dex2oat took 223.751ms (threads: 4) arena alloc=3MB java
>   alloc=206KB native alloc=5MB free=5MB I/dex2oat: /system/bin/dex2oat
>   --debuggable --dex-file=/data/data/com.company.package/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_8-classes.dex
>   --oat-file=/data/user/0/com.company.package/cache/slice-slice_8-classes.dex
>
> I/dex2oat: dex2oat took 515.355ms (threads: 4) arena alloc=855KB java
>   alloc=315KB native alloc=4MB free=2MB I/dex2oat: /system/bin/dex2oat
>   --debuggable --dex-file=/data/data/com.company.package/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_7-classes.dex
>   --oat-file=/data/user/0/com.company.package/cache/slice-slice_7-classes.dex

This went down 0(slice-slice_0-classes) then my splash screen launches.
Is this any memory issue or what i am doing wrong here.

---

Dependency

dependencies {

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.4.0'

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'

//3rd party
compile 'com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1@aar'
compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.4'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0'
compile 'com.github.lzyzsd:circleprogress:1.1.0@aar'
compile 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.10.1'

compile files('libs/pgsdk.jar')
compile files('libs/core.jar')
compile project(':commonslib')
compile project(':gcmlibrary')
compile project(':sdkui')
compile project(':PayU-release')


compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.4.0'
```

}

Comment: Did you try searching first  ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36575229/android-studio-2-0-pause-white-screen-on-app-first-run

Comment: Can You Show Me Your build.gradle file of your app Its Look like you are using more than 65536 methods thats for first time its taking more time

Comment: @HarshSharma i have added all dependency in the question

Comment: Did you disable insta run in your android studio? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35168753/instant-run-in-android-studio-2-0-how-to-turn-off

Comment: Yes, but that cause to increase my app size a lot. you have any idea why this happening?

Comment: What's the version? Release or debug? Does it happen in your release version? And do you use the instant run in Android Studio when the white screen appears?